# How to run selenium script using SoapUI - Groovy script?

Tags: selenium, groovy, automation, webdriver, soapui

I have written the following Selenium script in SoapUI - Groovy script test step.

```
openBrowser() // Invoke the method from groovy script

public void openBrowser()
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com");
    System.out.println("Application opened");
    System.out.println("Page Title is : "+driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
}
```

While running the above script, immediately I'm getting the error popup that says:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.findExecutable(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; error at line: 19
```

**FYI:**

**Chrome Browser Version : 66+ 

Selenium-alone-server : 3.12.0 

ChromeDriver Version : 2.38** 
SoapUI Tool Version : 5.3.0

How to resolve this issue for running from SoapUI tool?

**Note:**
The script is running from Eclipse IDE after adding the **selenium-standalone-server 3.12.0 jar** :(

Thanks,
Karunagara Pandi

Comment: As I didn't get correct answer for that question, I have posted again... :(

Comment: Hi, before looking at the software issue, can I ask why you want to run your Selenium tests from within SoapUI?  I use both, but my take is that whilst they're testing the same app (UI hitting API on backend), my Selenium tests are from a Java IDE and are not jumbled in with my SoapUI tests.  What benefit do you see with having both together?

Comment: If you move you Selenium tests into its own Java project, then you might be able to find the cause of the issue you're having.  For example, is the Java runtime SoapUI is running under compatible with the Selenium build?  Are you missing libraries?  Again, with something like Eclipse, Netbeans etc. you can see exactly what libraries you're running with.

Comment: If you must run within SoapUI, then get a least you first basic Selenium test running outside of SoapUI so you can work out what needs to be packed into SoapUI.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. My situation is, Have to invoke selenium part from SoapUI - Groovy script. In the UI, i have to pick one customerno and then need to use that customer number to the webservice which is present in SoapUI. That's why I used selenium script in the SoapUI. Meanwhile chrome browser got updated automatically, so that i got the above error i guess. I dont know which related jar should I use i.e. chrome driver & selenium standalone server.